# Can't ping server itself after connected to PPTP VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, iptables, pptp

I've set up a PPTP server on a CentOS 6.5 machine to use VPN from public networks and other miscellaneous scripts. Everything seem to be working OK except I can't ping the VPN server by its public IP or name once I get connected!

Let's say, I've got the following setup

### Server

```
host: vpn.myserver.com,
public ip: 178.62.x.x
private ip (pptp): 10.0.0.1
host range /dhcp: 10.0.0.100-200
```

### Client

```
private ip:= 10.241.0.76
```

Before I get connected to VPN, I can ping the server (by name or public IP) just fine. Once I am connected however, I have to use server's private address to ssh to the server.

Iptable rules (dumped to file)

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Sep 29 10:51:16 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3279:270754]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [16:1761]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [354:21503]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Sep 29 10:51:16 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Tue Sep 29 10:51:16 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [76829:9558834]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [67632:61015363]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [90822:67426561]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Sep 29 10:51:16 2015
```

Sysctl config:

```
# Controls IP packet forwarding
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

# Controls source route verification
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
```

Netstats

```
netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
10.0.0.100      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp0
10.0.0.101      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ppp1
178.62.xx.xx    0.0.0.0         255.255.192.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
10.131.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
0.0.0.0         178.62.xx.xx    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

Is there some routing rule missing?

### Update

Forgot to add traceroute details..

```
traceroute to 178.62.x.x (178.62.x.x), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  10.241.254.254 (10.241.254.254)  15.450 ms  15.955 ms  10.267 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
```